# how to get the span created dynamically inside an iframe?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor.Everything I write inside the editor is placed in p tag. But when I click the equation tool from toolbars,a dynamically span having class AMedit is created inside the p tag.My question is how to do some stuff or more simple just alert something when I focus the newly created span.Remember that the this span is contenteditable and also the whole editor comes from an Iframe.

Please have a look at the following link.

http://www.imathas.com/editordemo/demo.html

I have written the following code but id does not work for me.What is the error in my code.

```
var span = $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("span.AMedit");
var canPressEnter = true;
    span.on("focus", function(){
        canPressEnter = false;
    }).on("keypress", function(e){
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (canPressEnter === false && code === 13)
        {
            alert('welcome');
        }
    }).on("blur", function(){
        canPressEnter = true;
    });
   })
```

Please anyone can explain with a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem better with the  beyondthelogix.com link.

TinyMCE editor changes the class of the span from `AM` to `AMedit`. The solution I think about is to have a setInterval listening for that class change. I wrapped my code in a .ready() function.

Try this:

```
Add a line here:

tinyMCE.init({  
theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "elm1",
oninit: function() { loadlistener(); }, //add this line to run the next code under
setup : function(ed) {
```

and add this somewhere in the page:

```
var amedit = false;

function loadlistener() {
    console.log('load');
    $("#elm1_ifr").contents().keydown(function (e) {
        console.log('key');
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        console.log(code);
        if (code == 13 && amedit) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    var p_parent = $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("p");
    setInterval(function () {
        if (p_parent.find('span').length && p_parent.find('span').hasClass('AMedit')) {

            amedit = true;
        } else {
            amedit = false;
        }
    }, 200)
};
```

Comment: I have used your code but gives the following problem.

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Please can you explain with an example in jspaddle. I would be greatly thankful to you.

Comment: Please brother help me in this.it is very urgent for me.

Comment: @user2702406 do you have alive link? if you get that error its because you don't have a iframe with ID `elm1_ifr`

Comment: Please visit this and see the iframe in birebug.


http://beyondthelogix.com/demos/editordemo/demo.html

Comment: Please click the equation icon from toolbar,there automatically a span is created.Actually my main problem is that when I click inside the equation and press enter enter,the equation splits and the cursor goes to next line.I want to prevent this.If the cursor is inside the equation,the cursor should not got to new line on pressing enter key.Please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: @user2702406, did you try return false on keydown "enter" ?

Comment: Actually, I dont get the class of this span,that is why no event works for this.

Comment: Once I am able to get the class of this span, then i can do whatever i want with this.this span is automatically created when someone click on the equation icon in the toolbar.

Comment: Sorry brother it does not work as the span is not there when the document gets ready so document.ready function will not alert the message.The span comes when someone clicks on the equation icon.So what will be your suggestion in that case ?? Thanks

Comment: @user2702406, function .ready is for the TinyMCE, that inserts the iframe.

Comment: yes brother, I have tried.Dear brother if you dont mind please check your email.I have sent the files and the screenshot as attachment. Please forgive me But I need your help.I am very helpless at this time and need your help. thanks

Comment: Thanks brother,I got the alert message now. Brother today I have botherd you very much by asking so much questions.This is my last question.Now how can I find the focus event of this span. I am afraid that you will annoy but please forgive me.I want to put the preventDefault function on pressing enter key it the cursor is inside the span. Please brohter forgive me.Just answer to this last question of mine. Thanks my dear brother

Comment: @user2702406, will check that

Comment: Thanks brother, This is my last question.You are great. waiting for your reply. I will share all your profile including your website through all my social links.Thanks brother

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37831/discussion-between-user2702406-and-sergio)